# Using PsExec from batch and catching errors

Tags: windows, batch-file, remote-server, psexec

I need to run a command on a several hundred servers, and found PsExec from Sysinternals to be very useful. However, there is a small problem when the server is down or the application isn't installed. When this is the case, the error isn't logged to my output file.

How can I "log" the output from PsExec, when the server isn't responding? It should just be a line with "Offline" or "Error" in my output file.

My goal is to run a list of 800 servers and get a results.txt file with exactly 800 lines so I can paste the content into excel and compare the values.

My script looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set OUTPUT_FILE=result.txt
>nul copy nul %OUTPUT_FILE%
for /f %%i in (servers.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%x in ('psexec.exe \\%%i -u MyDomain\MyUsername -p MyPassword dspmqver -f 2') do (
        IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
            echo %%i %%y >>%OUTPUT_FILE%
        ) ELSE (
            echo Error
        )
    )
)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Best regards

Rasmus

Edit:

The output from the PsExec in a failing situation and a working one.

On a offline server, where it obviously fail - the output is:

```
psexec.exe \\hostname -u MyDomain\MyUsername -p MyUsername dspmqver -f 2

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Couldn't access hostname:
Network path not found (translated from danish)

Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on hostname
```

On a online server, where the script works - the output is.

```
psexec.exe \\hostname -u MyDomain\MyUsername -p MyUsername dspmqver -f 2


PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely

Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich

Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Version:     7.5.0.4
dspmqver exited on hostname with error code 0.
```

Comment: What is the output from a directly called psexec outside a batch ? Including the errorlevel

Comment: I just made a edit to the original post to add the output - could't use the code style in the comments here.

Answer (score 2):

`psexec -n 5` sets a 5 second timeout and the exit code is `1460` ([ERROR_TIMEOUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681385.aspx)).